# Can i extract data from Oracle Database using JavaScript but without using ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, oracle10g

I'm able to fetch data from Oracle database using ActiveXObject and JavaScript but I want to extract data from Oracle database and put data into an array without using ActiveXObject? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a client-side language with heavy restrictions. It can't on it's own connect to the database without a service providing that functionality.

I would recommend writing a simple RESTful service layer to handle these requests. It doesn't matter what language you want to do it in, but if you like javascript you can use NodeJS.

I'd suggest avoiding ActiveXObject unless you want to write an IE specific application. Which makes me want to cry.